# tabularray table nesting and alignment issues

Tags: tables, alignment, tabularray

When drawing nested tables with tabularray, I cannot accurately align them within the surrounding table.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]||X[l,m]|}, 
        rowspec={X[c,m,25.5pt]X[c,m,200pt]},
    }
         \hline 
         \SetCell[c=5]{l}{ 检测细胞： \quad  }&&&& \\ 
         \hline
         \SetCell[c=2]{l,h}{ 检测细胞： \quad  }&&\SetCell[c=3]{l,h}{ 
             \begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
                 \hline
                 1 & 2 \\
                 \hline
                 3 & 4 \\
                 \hline
              \end{tblr}
         }&& \\
         \hline 
     \end{tblr}
 \end{document}
```

This is **my result**:
[image]

It can be seen that when there is no nested table, the `l,h` parameter works normally. However, when the table is nested within the cell, the `h` parameter in the `l,h` fails to align the nested table to the head, as expected.

**Additionally**, I wrapped the cell contents with a `minipage` environment, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

With the inner array built with `tabularray` I was not successful. If using `tabular` is sufficient for you, I suggest:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694691/tabularray-table-nesting-and-alignment-issues
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={*{5}{X}}, 
        rowspec={X[25.5pt]*{2}{X[200pt]}},
        cell{1}{1} = {r=1,c=5}{l},
        cell{2-3}{1} = {r=1,c=2}{l,h},
        cell{2-3}{3} = {r=1,c=3}{l,h},
        hlines,vlines
    }
        检测细胞:&&&& \\ 
        检测细胞:&&
        With \texttt{tabularray}\ %
            \begin{tblr}[t]{|c|c|}
                \hline
                1 & 2 \\
                \hline
                3 & 4 \\
                \hline
            \end{tblr}
            don't work\\
        检测细胞:&&
        With \texttt{tabular}\ %
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            1 & 2 \\
            \hline
            3 & 4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        work
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]